# Why does calling History.pushState() (or .replaceState()) trigger a 'popstate' event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, history, pushstate, popstate

I am changing the url depending upon an AJAX call.

```
window.history.pushState("", "", ''+newUrlWithParameters);
```

Also I have a popstate event written within my JS.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
   //... do this
});
```

As soon as The pushState is being called, the popstate is triggered.
How to prevent this?

Comment: Can you add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Because for me it works as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/j0gywrdh/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - solved it by adding

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

to the calling event's handler (they handle a click event on an HTML a element, and tracing through jquery the mouseevent seemed to want to trigger the popState).